# How to put a limiter on a command and at the end of that time it force the interruption?

Tags: windows, powershell

I built a script that gets data from a device remotely, here are some of them

```
Test-NetConnection $ComputerName -Port 5985 -InformationLevel Quiet -WarningAction SilentlyContinue

Get-CimInstance Win32_SystemEnclosure -ComputerName $ComputerName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ChassisTypes

gwmi win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $ComputerName | Select-Object @{Label="LastBootTime"; Expression={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastBootUpTime)}} | Select -ExpandProperty LastBootTime).tostring("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```

As you can see, there are several commands that need to get remote information. But in Test-NetConnection sometimes it executes the command quickly and sometimes it doesn't, when it's not fast, it takes forever to complete and report me an error, and not only this command, the ones that start with "gwmi" too ( these are the ones that most exhibit this behavior). Running them in a powershell_ise, when they take too long, even pressing CTRL+C, powershell has a lot of difficulties to finish the command and gets the status "Stopping". How do I put a limiter for these commands (eg 5 seconds) where after that 5 seconds and force stop that command at any cost (without killing the script of course) and continue or display an error message?

Another help is that in commands like "gwmi" and "Get-CimInstance" I sometimes have that error "The RPC service is not available" how do I catch this error and customize an error message to put a "break" in the Final? Because when RPC is unavailable, I know that all other commands will have the same error, so if in the first command it already finds this error, I warn you by putting a message and stop the script execution.

Comment: No, I fixed the typo, but that's not the reason.

Comment: That's the typical behavior of WMI queries. I work around such problems by using jobs to run the concerned commands (i.e. start-job) that can be stopped after a timeout period.

Comment: How would I go about preventing this from happening, could it help?

Comment: To actually be able to kill a command taking too long, that command has to be a separate process.

Comment: Suggested reading: https://lowleveldesign.org/2019/01/31/limit-the-execution-time-of-a-process-tree-on-windows/

Comment: I tested it with some powershell commands like Test-NetConnection but I couldn't program the output to procgov

Answer (score 0):

This is the script, and the fix I'm looking for is when it makes the test-netconnection capture the RPC error and interrupt the script's execution, otherwise it will continue the only error where it prevents from collecting the information is the RPC.

in the following WMI Query commands, it would also be interesting to put the RPC catch, but the most important thing is not to take so long, in a test here, the command was running for more than 5 minutes and I couldn't stop it, except by killing the process from powershell.exe

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
$ComputerHost = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter the Hostname of the machine", "Audit Report")
If ($ComputerHost -eq "")
{
    break
}


Write-Progress -Activity "Validating if $ComputerHost is on the network" -PercentComplete 10
Write-Progress -Activity "Validating if $ComputerHost is on the network" -PercentComplete 10
Start-Sleep 1

#Performing validation if the equipment is on the network, if so, the script will continue, otherwise, it will be canceled informing that the equipment has insufficient requirements for the operation.
$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
try {
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";
    $TestComputerHost = Test-Connection $ComputerHost -Count 1 -InformationAction Continue -WarningAction SilentlyContinue;
} catch {
    [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::MsgBox("Computer $ComputerHost is not responding on the network.", "OKOnly,SystemModal,Critical", "Error") | Out-Null;
    break;
    } finally {
    $ProgressPreference = 'Continue'
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
    }

Write-Progress -Activity "Validating if the remote service is enabled" -PercentComplete 15
Write-Progress -Activity "Validating if the remote service is enabled" -PercentComplete 15
Start-Sleep 1

$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
$TestComputerHost = Test-NetConnection $ComputerHost -Port 5985 -InformationLevel Quiet -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
If ($TestComputerHost -ne "False"){
    [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::MsgBox("WARNING: Computer $ComputerHost is responding on the network but has not identified remote management enabled, some data may be incomplete!", "OKOnly,SystemModal,Exclamation", "Warning") | Out-Null
}
$ProgressPreference = 'Continue'

Write-Progress -Activity "Loading modules and functions" -PercentComplete 20
Start-Sleep 1

#Function to create the Get-WUChassisType that is performed to find out if the Chassis of the equipment is Notebook or Desktop, and it is not configured to detect virtual machine
Function Get-WUCchassisType {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    stop (
    )
    Set-StrictMode -Version 'Latest'
    [int[]]$chassisType = try {
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";
    Get-CimInstance Win32_SystemEnclosure -ComputerName $ComputerHost | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ChassisTypes;
    } catch {
    Write-Warning "WARNING: It was not possible to get the user logged into the remote equipment!";
    } finally {
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Continue";
    }
    switch($chassisType) {
        { $_ -in 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 15, 16 } {
            return 'Desktop'
        }
        { $_ -in 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 18, 21, 31, 32 } {
            return 'Notebook'
        }
        { $_ -in 30 } {
            return 'Tablet'
        }
        { $_ -in 17, 23 } {
            return 'Server'
        }
        Default {
        }
    }
}


#Function to get the last logged in user
Function Get-LastUser {
Get-WmiObject Win32_LoggedOnUser -ComputerName $ComputerHost |
    Select Antecedent -Unique |
    % {
        $domain = $_.Antecedent.Split('"')[1]
        if($domain -eq "VLINET") {
            "{0}\{1}" -f $domain, $_.Antecedent.Split('"')[3]
        }
    } | Select-Object -First 1
    }


Write-Progress -Activity "Creating the base of the report" -PercentComplete 25
Write-Progress -Activity "Creating the base of the report" -PercentComplete 25
Start-Sleep 1

#HTML Report - Report generated in...
$output+="<tr><td><b>Report generated in</b> " + (Get-Date -UFormat "%d/%m/%Y %R:%S") + "</td> </tr>`n"

Write-Progress -Activity "Creating the base of the report" -PercentComplete 30
Write-Progress -Activity "Creating the base of the report" -PercentComplete 30
Start-Sleep 1

#HTML Report - Audit Report
$output+="<h1>Audit Report</h1><br>"

Write-Progress -Activity "Creating the base of the report" -PercentComplete 35
Write-Progress -Activity "Creating the base of the report" -PercentComplete 35
Start-Sleep 1

#HTML Report - Computer
$output+="<table><tr><td><h1><b>Computer:`n`n</b>"+$ComputerHost+"</h1></td></tr>`n"

Write-Progress -Activity "Getting logged in user remotely" -PercentComplete 40
Write-Progress -Activity "Getting logged in user remotely" -PercentComplete 40
Start-Sleep 1

#HTML Report - Currently Connected User:
$output+="<table><tr><td><table><tr><td><tr><td><b>Currently logged in user:`n`n</b>"+((Get-LastUser ).Split('\')[1])+"</td></tr>"

Write-Progress -Activity "Getting booting data" -PercentComplete 45
Write-Progress -Activity "Getting booting data" -PercentComplete 45
Start-Sleep 1

#HTML Report - Last Boot Time
$output+="<table><tr><td><table><tr><b>Last Boot Time:`n`n</b>"+(gwmi win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $ComputerHost | Select-Object @{ Label="LastBootTime"; Expression={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastBootUpTime)}} | Select -ExpandProperty LastBootTime).tostring("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss") +"</td>< /tr>"

# Just whitespace to make the HTML more readable and organized
$output+="<td><tr></td></tr><br>"
$output+="<td><tr></td></tr>"
$output+="<td><tr></td></tr><br>"
$output+="<td><tr></td></tr>"

Write-Progress -Activity "Getting equipment chassis" -PercentComplete 50
Write-Progress -Activity "Getting equipment chassis" -PercentComplete 50
Start-Sleep 1
$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

#HTML Report - Equipment Type
$Output+="<tr><td><table><tr><b>Equipment Type: </b>`n`n"+(Get-WUChassisType)

# Just whitespace to make the HTML more readable and organized
$output+="<tr><tr><tr><tr><tr><tr>"
$ProgressPreference = 'Continue'

Write-Progress -Activity "Getting data from operating system" -PercentComplete 55
Write-Progress -Activity "Getting data from operating system" -PercentComplete 55
Start-Sleep 1

#HTML Report - Operating System
$Output+="<tr><td><table><tr><b>Operating System:</b>`n`n"+(gwmi -class win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $ComputerHost).caption

Write-Progress -Activity "Getting data from OS" -PercentComplete 60
Write-Progress -Activity "Getting data from OS" -PercentComplete 60
Start-Sleep 1

#HTML Report - Installed on (Gets the date when Windows was installed on the device)
$Output+="</table></td>`n<td width=`"10`"></td><td valign=`"top`"><b>     Installed on:`n`n</ b>"+([WMI]'').ConvertToDateTime((gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $ComputerHost).InstallDate).tostring("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss")+"</b></td ></t>`n"

# Just whitespace to make the HTML more readable and organized
$output+="<td><tr></td></tr><br>"
$output+="<td><tr></td></tr>"

Write-Progress -Activity "Getting data from processor" -PercentComplete 65
Write-Progress -Activity "Getting data from processor" -PercentComplete 65
Start-Sleep 1

#HTML Report - Processor
$output+="<table><tr><td><table><tr><b>Processor:</b>`n`n"+(gwmi win32_processor -ComputerName $ComputerHost -filter "deviceid='CPU0'" -property name |select -exp name) +"</td></tr>"

# Just whitespace to make the HTML more readable and organized
$output+="<td><tr></td></tr><br>"
$output+="<td><tr></td></tr>"

Write-Progress -Activity "Getting data from disk" -PercentComplete 70
Write-Progress -Activity "Getting data from disk" -PercentComplete 70
Start-Sleep 1

#HTML Report - Disk
$output+="<table><tr><b>Disk:`n`n</b>" +(gwmi -class Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $ComputerHost | Measure-Object -Property size -Sum | % {[Math]: :Round(($_.sum / 1GB),2)})+"GB`n"

# Just whitespace to make the HTML more readable and organized
$output+="<td><tr></td></tr><br>"
$output+="<td><tr></td></tr>"

Write-Progress -Activity "Getting data from memory" -PercentComplete 75
Write-Progress -Activity "Getting data from memory" -PercentComplete 75
Start-Sleep 1

#HTML Report - RAM Memory
$output+="<table><tr><b>RAM:`n`n</b>" +(gwmi -class Win32_PhysicalMemory -ComputerName $ComputerHost | Measure-Object -Property capacity -Sum | % {[Math] ::Round(($_.sum / 1GB),2)})+"GB`n"

# Just whitespace to make the HTML more readable and organized
$output+="<td><tr></td></tr><br>"
$output+="<td><tr></td></tr>"

Write-Progress -Activity "Getting data from memory" -PercentComplete 80
Write-Progress -Activity "Getting data from memory" -PercentComplete 80
Start-Sleep 1

#HTML Report - Serial Number
$output+="<table><tr><b>Serial Number:</b>`n`n"+(gwmi win32_bios -ComputerName $ComputerHost -property SerialNumber |select -exp SerialNumber) +"</td>< /tr>"

# Just whitespace to make the HTML more readable and organized
$output+="<td><tr></td></tr><br>"
$output+="<td></td></tr>"

Write-Progress -Activity "Getting data from BIOS" -PercentComplete 85
Write-Progress -Activity "Getting data from BIOS" -PercentComplete 85
Start-Sleep 1

#HTML Report - Manufacturer
$output+="<table><tr><b>Manufacturer:</b>`n`n"+(gwmi win32_ComputerSystemProduct -ComputerName $ComputerHost -property Vendor |select -exp Vendor) +"</td></tr >"

# Just whitespace to make the HTML more readable and organized
$output+="<td><tr></td></tr><br>"
$output+="<td></td></tr>"

Write-Progress -Activity "Validating data and saving the report" -PercentComplete 90
Write-Progress -Activity "Validating data and saving the report" -PercentComplete 90
Start-Sleep 1

#HTML Report - Template
$output+="<table><tr><b>Model:</b>`n`n"+(gwmi win32_ComputerSystemProduct -ComputerName $ComputerHost -property Name |select -exp Name) +"</td></tr >"

Write-Progress -Activity "Validating data and saving the report" -PercentComplete 95
Write-Progress -Activity "Validating data and saving the report" -PercentComplete 95
Start-Sleep 1

# Output to export the report file
Out-File -FilePath ".\$ComputerHost-$((Get-Date).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm"))_Report.html" -Encoding default -InputObject $output

# Makes a copy of the report file to a temporary folder, where it will be executed as soon as the script finishes
Copy-Item -Path ".\$ComputerHost-$((Get-Date).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm"))_Report.html" -Destination "$env:TEMP\$ComputerHost.html " -Force

Write-Progress -Activity "Validating data and saving the report" -Completed
Start-Sleep 1

#Performs a conditional structure validation to define which browser is the default on the local user's computer.
$Reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('CurrentUser', $env:COMPUTERNAME)
$RegKey= $Reg.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice")
$BrowserProgId = $RegKey.GetValue("ProgId")
$BrowserProgId = $BrowserProgId.Split('-')[0]

if ($BrowserProgId -eq "ChromeHTML") {
$DefaultBrowser="chrome.exe"}

elseif ($BrowserProgId -eq "MSEDgeHTM") {
$DefaultBrowser = "msedge.exe"}

elseif ($BrowserProgId -eq "FirefoxURL") {
$DefaultBrowser = "firefox.exe"}

[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::MsgBox("Report generated successfully!", "OKOnly,SystemModal,Information", "Success") | Out-Null

#Initializes the report file that was previously copied to the temp folder invoking the user-defined default browser.
cmd.exe /c "start $DefaultBrowser "%temp%\$ComputerHost.html""

Start-Sleep 10
Remove-Item -Path "$env:TEMP\$ComputerHost.html" -Force | Out-Null

# Clear the main variable, useful if this is running in a powershell_ise
Clear-Variable output
```